# Installing Memcached 1.4.2.0 from Source On LEMP Server and making it talk to PHP5-Memcached

Tags: php, linux, memcached

Using:  Ubuntu 14.01 LTS in a LEMP Stack

I have managed to install Memcached from source and also have installed PHP5-memcached.

How do I know if the 2 are talking to each other?

Is there some configuration that I need to change and if so I would really appreciate any help on this?

Also I would like to monitor and see how memcached if being used.

I use a VPS server with about 2GB of RAM and will be installing wordpress on the LEMP stack.

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you install it from source code? There is a package available and it's of a **newer** (by 4.5 years!!!) version than you're trying to install.

Comment: Memcached is the latest version so that leaves the PHP5-memcached package.Is this really 4.5 years old??? I am installing Memcached from source because the package available in the Ubuntu repository is quite old - like you said……… 4.5 years old.

Comment: Memcached 1.4.2 was released 4.5 years ago, right. "package available in the Ubuntu repository is quite old - like you said" --- please provide the exact numbers. What is the version from ubuntu repository. I see quite new there.

Comment: The Ubuntu repos are running memcached 1.4.14  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memcached. The current version is 1.4.20 which is the latest.That is why I am installing from source.

Comment: according question subject you are installing 1.4.2.0, not 1.4.20

Comment: My bad..really sorry..that was a typo..there is no version 1.4.2.0 - only version 1.4.20.Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: okay. Next question: why not install 1.4.14

Comment: There isnt a repository for the latest version of memcached anywhere - I have checked but maybe I could have missed it - so I want to work with the latest version and then go on and create a repository that everyone can use.Besides, it has numerous enhancements and fixes so why not.The current verison on Ubunutu's repo is over 2 years old…A lot has happened since then.

Comment: what "a lot"? Do you or your app really rely on any of those changes? What particularly?

Comment: I have installed my LEMP server with the latest of everything - Linux,Nginx, etc.I need a bleeding-edge server with all the latest fixes, enhances, etc.

Comment: I want to preferably create a Memcached repo that will have the latest fixes the will work with a PHP client - preferably PHP5-memcached.The Ubuntu repos are too behind for my liking.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to check if Memcached is running is phpMemcachedAdmin

https://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

It's like phpMyAdmin (for MySQL), but for Memcached